# Jackson JSON processing - static ObjectMapper vs one instance for every serialization and deserialization

Tags: json, jackson

Is it better to use one static instance of an ObjectMapper or create an instance of ObjectMapper for every serialization or deserialization?

Comment: Please, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-make-jacksons-objectmapper-as-static-final

Comment: Thanks, Michal Ziober. The reason I asked for is that my application has to parse json strings with different date formats. If my ObjectMapper is a static instance, I then need to change the configuration each time and reset it back to default every time I want to parse different date formats. Any pointers there?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, every time when you want to parse JSON, you are doing something like that: 1. objectMapper.setDateFormat(NEW_DATE_FORMAT), 2. Deserialize JSON, 3.objectMapper.setDateFormat(DEFAULT_FORMAT), don't you? How many different date formats do you have? Could you show a simple source code how are you doing it?

Comment: Michael - It is exactly as in the steps you had mentioned above. Since, the mapper is a static instance, the configuration is visible application wide. So, any time I set a new date format and parse a JSON, I will have to reset it to the default. As of now, I might have a couple of formats.

Comment: If you use Jackson 2.x, you should be using single `ObjectMapper`, but multiple `ObjectReader` and/or `ObjectWriter` instances: latter are safe to configure on per-call basis. Same is NOT true for `ObjectMapper`.