# Create Unique Configuration between multiple Jackson mappers

Tags: java, jackson, export-to-csv, objectmapper, xmlmapper

Is there any interface in `Jackson`, or a better way to create the same configuration for multiple object mappers?
For example, I have this both methods for the same class:

```java
public static File toCsv(List<Entity> entityList) {

    final File tempFile = new File(CSV_FILE_NAME);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();

    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules()
        .configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true)
        .addMixIn(Entity.class, EntityMixIn.class)
        .addMixIn(EntityB.class, EntityBMixIn.class);
      CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(Entity.class).withHeader();

    try {
      mapper.writer(schema).writeValue(tempFile,entityList);
      return tempFile;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
public static File toXml(List<Entity> entityList) {

    final File tempFile = new File(XML_FILE_NAME);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();

    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules()
        .configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true)
        .addMixIn(Entity.class, EntityMixIn.class)
        .addMixIn(EntityB.class, EntityBMixIn.class);

    try {
      mapper.writeValue(tempFile, entityList);
      return tempFile;

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

And both have exactly the same configuration, if in the future i need a new format, i could probably use the same configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For defining `MixIn` and custom serialisers/deserialisers you can use `SimpleModule`. For enabling/disabling features on `ObjectMapper` you can create a method.

```
class MapperFactory {

  private final ObjectMapper jsonMapper = configure(new ObjectMapper());
  private final XmlMapper xmlMapper = configure(new XmlMapper());
  private final CsvMapper csvMapper = configure(new CsvMapper());

  public ObjectMapper getJsonMapper() {
    return jsonMapper;
  }

  public XmlMapper getXmlMapper() {
    return xmlMapper;
  }

  public CsvMapper getCsvMapper() {
    return csvMapper;
  }

  public <T extends ObjectMapper> T configure(T mapper) {
    // configure mapper instance if required
    mapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
    // register default
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    // register custom
    mapper.registerModule(createCustomModule());

    return mapper;
  }

  public SimpleModule createCustomModule() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("EntityMixIns");
    module.setMixInAnnotation(Entity.class, EntityMixIn.class);
    // more MixIns

    return module;
  }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new MapperFactory();

    System.out.println("JSON:");
    System.out.println(mapperFactory.getJsonMapper().writeValueAsString(new Entity()));

    System.out.println("XML:");
    System.out.println(mapperFactory.getXmlMapper().writeValueAsString(new Entity()));

    System.out.println("CSV:");
    CsvMapper csvMapper = mapperFactory.getCsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.schemaFor(Entity.class).withHeader();
    System.out.println(csvMapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(new Entity()));
  }
}

class Entity {
  private int id = 12;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "A{" + "id=" + id + '}';
  }
}

interface EntityMixIn {

  @JsonProperty("_idName")
  int getId();
}
```

Above code prints:

```
JSON:
{"_idName":12}
XML:
<Entity><_idName>12</_idName></Entity>
CSV:
_idName
12
```

See also:

- [Should I declare Jackson's ObjectMapper as a static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-declare-jacksons-objectmapper-as-a-static-field)
- [How do I correctly reuse Jackson ObjectMapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611565/how-do-i-correctly-reuse-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you ;)

Comment: @TelmoFrancisco, I'm glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, you can accept and upvote it.