# Jackson ObjectMapper - does changing configurations on ObjectReader impact usage of ObjectMapper by multiple threads

Tags: java, json, jackson

We have a Spring based application and we have defined a singleton bean for Jackson `ObjectMapper` class.

```
@Bean(name = "jacksonObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
  return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

We have a use case to write a generic JSON Serializer/Deserializer which we wrote in following way:

```
public <T, U> T deserialize(final String inputJsonString, final Class<T> targetType, final Class<U> targetParameterType) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
  return objectMapper
    .reader(objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(targetType, targetParameterType))
    .without(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
    .readValue(inputJsonString);
}
```

Here I am using `ObjectReader` instead of `ObjectMapper` itself and changing some configurations on `ObjectReader` (e.g. `.without(...)`). My question is, will such configuration changes impact other threads which may be using the same `ObjectMapper` instance to do something else (may be simply deserializing or serializing)?

Could someone help me understand the details and guide me?

My apologies if I haven't explained the question clearly; please let me know and I can provide further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, `ObjectReader` configuration does not change the underlying `ObjectMapper` configuration.

**Explanation:** If you use the `ObjectMapper` directly and alter the configuration of the mapper it can lead to problems if the mapper is shared between multiple threads. However, if you do not change the underlying config you should be safe anyway (more reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-make-jacksons-objectmapper-as-static-final#answer-3909846)).

In your case you are calling the `mapper.reader(...)` method where you actually create an `ObjectReader`. The `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` are immutable and therefore they never change the underlying state. Furthermore, even if you change the config of the underlying `ObjectMapper` the reader will not be affected.

Note that for each call to the `mapper.reader(...)` method you are creating a new `ObjectReader` so if you change your `ObjectMapper` config between calls to the `reader` method you may run into problems.

So, to summarize: If you create an `ObjectReader` and use the same reader in your thread you are safe.

Comment: Thank you @wassgren, appreciate your help.