# Speeding up Jackson: 45 MB of JSON takes 10 minutes to generate

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a big PoJo, which translates into a 45 MB JSON string. I am using Jackson, and the `writeValueAsString` method is taking more than 10–15 minutes to generate it.

If I generate a chunk of it, everything works reasonably quickly.

I looked at `Gson` metrics and it seems slower than Jackson.

How could I speed it up?

Code is very straight-forward:

```
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
```

Comment: It can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836666/jackson-writevalueasstring-too-slow

Comment: Any profiler results?

Comment: 45Mb of json that's a beast..

Comment: 45MB doesn't sound 'plain old' to me!

Comment: At that file size, you should be streaming instead of working with strings.

Comment: `I have a big PoJo, which translates into a 45 MB JSON string` -- you're doing it wrong. Sorry but thats reality. Split that thing into (many) objects which get SELECTED individually - you may save vast amounts of data that way.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, No profiler results yet.

@specializt You mind explaining `you may save vast amounts of data that way` part. I didn't understand that.

Trying to stream it now, maybe that would help.

Comment: thats easy : 45MB JSON data (very) likely includes unneeded data, simply select your NECESSARY data and transfer it chunkwise. Whats not to understand? You probably should'nt write software if you cant split up data packets ... thats pretty much programming basics.