# Is it safe to use SimpleDateFormat in fasterxml's ObjectMapper

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc

everyone!

I know SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe,we shouldn't use a single instance in a multithreading environment!

ObjectMapper is thread safe, which is good.

now i'm wondering is it safe to use SimpleDateFormat in ObjectMapper!
here's my custom ObjectMapper:

```
public class MyObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public MyObjectMapper() {
        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }

}
```

and I'm using it in springmvc's configuration.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new MyObjectMapper());
    converters.add(jsonConverter);
}
```

If yes, how ObjectMapper did it!

If no, what's DateFormat should i use!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using it with ObjectMapper! I think maybe ObjectMapper have some synchronizing mechanism to keep it safe!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See comments of @StaxMan on [Should I declare Jackson's ObjectMapper as a static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-declare-jacksons-objectmapper-as-a-static-field)

Baseline:

`DateFormat` is cloned within Jackson, so it's safe to use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks!it's really helpful.