# JSON to Java object deserialization with escaped properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to convert the following JSON to Java object. The property `providerResponse` in the JSON contains map of properties but they are escaped and wrapped in doubleQuotes. As a result, it does not deserialize the property `providerResponse` into a Java object (it comes as `String`). I use `objectMapper.readValue(msgStr, classType)` to deserialize the JSON. The message is generated by AWS for SNS delivery status notifications and I don't have control to change the JSON message. Is it possible to configure `ObjectMapper` to unescape the property and deserialize into a Java object instead of `String`?

```
{  
   "delivery":{  
      "providerResponse":"{\"sqsRequestId\":\"308ee0c6-7d51-57b0-a472-af8e6c41be0b\",\"sqsMessageId\":\"88dd59eb-c34d-4e4d-bb27-7e0d226daa2a\"}"
   }
}

@JsonProperty("providerResponse")
private String providerResponse;
```

Comment: I've used gson for this, which forces you to create a class that defines the json, including any other classes. That is, we don't want to accept this label as a string, but rather tell the serializer what sort of object it is.

Comment: thx jdv. gson has not been used in this project so far. will review.

Comment: Oh, I assumed Jackson has the same functionality, which according to the answer you have accepted, seems to be the case -- a class and annotations for mapping JSON <-> objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to configure `ObjectMapper` to handle this behavior by default. The solution is to create a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html?is-external=true):

```
public class Wrapper {
    public Delivery delivery;
}

public class Delivery {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProviderResponseDeserializer.class)
    public ProviderResponse providerResponse;
}

public class ProviderResponse {
    public String sqsRequestId;
    public String sqsMessageId;
}

public class ProviderResponseDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ProviderResponse> {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public ProviderResponse deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.readValue(jsonParser.getText(), ProviderResponse.class);
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize the JSON by using your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Wrapper wrapper = mapper.readValue(JSON, Wrapper.class);
```

Comment: thx Casey. works like a charm. Would it be okay to instantiate ObjectMapper() every time we deserialize a message? Would it have performance hits for system under heavy load (1 million deserializations in a day)?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I don't think it would be an issue at all. If you'd rather not instantiate it every time though, [`ObjectMapper` is thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3909846/2446208), so it's completely fine to use a `static` instance of it inside your `ProviderResponseDeserializer` (updated the answer as this seems to be the preferred way).

Comment: @Casey : I have this similar issue. I tried your solution. I get an error saying `no single string constructor defined`. I searched for the solution for this error. I came to know that I have to define a constructor for `ProviderResponse` class which takes the json string as an argument and then sets the properties from that json. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this similar issue. This gets resolved if we define a constructor in `ProviderResponse` which takes a single string argument (which is actually json) and then map the json in the constructor to the instance of `ProviderResponse` and use this temp instance to initialise the properties.

```
public class Wrapper {
    public Delivery delivery;
}

public class Delivery {
    public ProviderResponse providerResponse;
}

public class ProviderResponse {
    public String sqsRequestId;
    public String sqsMessageId;

    private static ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ProviderResponse(String json) {
        ProviderResponse temp = objMapper.readValue(json, ProviderResponse.class);
        this.sqsMessageId = temp.sqsMessageId;
        this.sqsRequestId = temp.sqsRequestId;
    }
}
```

The key is to keep the `ObjectMapper` instance and the its usage somewhere in your utility class and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Although @blacktide solution looks fine I have found it not working for me. Maybe because of Scala not Java, maybe because of library versions. @blacktide code causes StackOverflow for me. I used intermediate wrapper class to avoid the issue.
Tested for "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.11.3".

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationContext, JsonDeserializer, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize

final case class Wrapper(@JsonProperty("delivery") delivery:Delivery)

final case class Delivery(@JsonProperty("providerResponse") providerResponseWrapper: ProviderResponseWrapper) // field name provided to be read as "providerResponse"

@JsonDeserialize(using = classOf[ProviderResponseWrapperDeserializer])
final case class ProviderResponseWrapper(@JsonProperty("providerResponse") providerResponse: ProviderResponse)

final case class ProviderResponse(@JsonProperty("sqsRequestId") sqsRequestId: String, @JsonProperty("sqsMessageId") sqsMessageId: String)

final case class ProviderResponseWrapperDeserializer() extends JsonDeserializer[ProviderResponseWrapper] {
  override def deserialize(jsonParser: JsonParser, deserializationContext: DeserializationContext): ProviderResponseWrapper =
    ProviderResponseWrapper(new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonParser.getText, classOf[ProviderResponse])) // mapper may be moved to the object
}
```

It outputs:

```
Wrapper(Delivery(ProviderResponseWrapper(ProviderResponse(308ee0c6-7d51-57b0-a472-af8e6c41be0b,88dd59eb-c34d-4e4d-bb27-7e0d226daa2a))))
```

Please pay attention to provide proper name for providerResponseWrapper using annotation.