# Is it safe to use a static object in a non-static method when multiple threads are accessing it?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, non-static

My class looks something like this:

```
public Class A {

     private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

     public String get(String key) {
          JsonNode nod = mapper.readTree(getFromCache(key));
     }
}
```

Multiple threads would be accessing this method. Do I need to synchronize it? Do I need to move the mapper inside the method?

Comment: If that's the Objectmapper from Jackson Library,  the answer seems to be that it is safe (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3907929/5077154).  However,  the general answer to your question is "it depends".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the implementation of `ObjectMapper`.  For a possible answer, see: 
[Should I declare Jackson's ObjectMapper as a static field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-declare-jacksons-objectmapper-as-a-static-field?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It is not possible to tell from the code sample you have provided because we don't know what that `ObjectMapper` is.

To find the answer you would need to check the javadoc of `ObjectMapper`.  Or failing that, the implementation.

If you are unsure, you could:

- create a new `ObjectMapper` inside the method so there is a new object each time,
- create a ThreadLocal, so each thread has it's own object

Creating objects is very cheap on the JVM (unless they do expensive operations like scanning the class path, etc).

Comment: And if you use `ThreadLocal`, beware of "leaks" from long-lived threads like thread pool workers.  The thread local object will hang around as long as the thread is alive, even if the thread ends up being assigned to some completely different task.

Comment: Yes, the ObjectMapper is the import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

Answer (score 0):

There is one copy of static variable per class-loader that loaded this class. This more-or-less means per-process, however you need to be aware of the difference.

E.g. when two web-apps have the same class bundled, the class will be loaded twice, thus having two copies of the same static field.

If you need a variable having independent value on a thread basis, have a look at ThreadLocal

Answer (score 0):

As WW. mentioned it is dependent upon the `ObjectMapper.readTree` implementation. There are multiple factors which decides whether the method is thread safe or not.

Like :

1. Whether the method is synchronized or not
2. Does method uses variables which are declared outside the method