# For Jackson, How to safely share an ObjectMapper ? Is there any immutable ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Mapper instances are fully thread-safe, there is no need to create a mapper for single use, but mapper's config can be changed.

Although ObjectMapper has [copy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#copy()) function to duplicate the config for customize based on exists mapper, if I share a mapper, there is no guarantee that when someone want to customize the mapper, they will copy the shared mapper. So I want a immutable mapper to share, if someone accidently changed the shared mapper, some exception should be throw.

Is there something like this ?

Comment: I will create a wrapper of ObjectMapper and just public some needed functions

Comment: On the contrary, I just want to hide some function to prevent config change, this seems very common use case, is there any exists wrapper for this ? If no, I will create one for myself.

Comment: One option could be to share an `ObjectWriter` instance instead of an `ObjectMapper`. That class appears at first glance to be immutable, although I believe it's not the intended purpose of it.

Comment: @Henrik But from ObjectWriter can not clone a ObjectMapper.

Comment: @wener: You shouldn't need to do that. Create a correctly configured `ObjectMapper` and then provide instances of `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter` to the parts of the code where you're afraid someone might change the configuration. See this answer for more details : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3909846/13075

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! If there is no immutable `ObjectMapper`, use immutable `ObjectReader` or `ObjectWriter` instead.

Comment: @wener: No problem. Just learned this myself during research. :)

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to not share the `ObjectMapper` instance, but rather configure it correctly and then share instances of `ObjectWriter` and `ObjectReader` created by the `ObjectMapper`.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
// Configure to your needs
om.enable(...);
om.disable(...);

// Distribute these to the parts of the program where you fear configuration changes.
ObjectWriter writer = om.writer();
ObjectReader reader = om.reader();
```

This also seems to be the approach favoured by the developers of Jackson: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909846/13075