Is this Java static method thread-safe with pojo object as parameter?
Java class:
public class User {
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
}


My UtilityClass:
public class UtilityClass {

    public static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public string static objToString(User user) {
         return mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    }

}

Is the above Utility class static method thread-safe?
Note: The user object is always created within a non-static private method from different class and then calls the static method to get the object's JSON string.
I feel it is thread-safe since it not exposed at class level and the static method does not change the user object within.

We cannot know if it is thread safe. The thread safety depends completely on ObjectMapper. If ObjectMapper is able to lock User or otherwise prevent race conditions, then the method is thread safe. Or inversely, since we do not know that it is thread safe, we must assume that it is not thread safe.

Assuming ObjectMapper comes from Jackson (if so, please add tag), then yes, your objToString method is thread-safe.

@k314159 For it to be thread safe, the read operations must also be protected from concurrent write operations.

@Torben do you mean some other method might be changing the content of user while ObjectMapper is trying to read it?

If you make the class User immutable (i.e. all fields private and themselves being of immutable type) then your static method objToString would be thread-safe. Also consider making it a record.

@k314159 - Thanks! I updated the tag.  Unfortunately, the User object is not owned by us. So, won't be able to make it a record.

BTW the method being static is not relevant (even a static method can be called multiple times in different threads)

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907929/should-i-declare-jacksons-objectmapper-as-a-static-field


Is the above Utility class static method thread-safe?

It is not.
It is about process, not methods.
Mostly, a process is or is not thread safe; a single method call is merely part of a process. For example, given a new Hashtable() (or, if you prefer in more modern style, Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap())), all methods in that are 'thread safe'; that's specifically what synchronizedMap does. Nevertheless, this extremely simple code would not be thread safe:
Map threadSafeMap = ....;

if (!threadSafeMap.containsKey("Hello")) {
  threadSafeMap.put("Hello", someCalculation());
}

That's because 2 threads can simultaneously get to the containsKey call, simultaneously (and thread safely) both determine that Hello is not in there, and then both do the expensive calculation which is presumably not thread safe, at least, if the intent of this code is that the calculation is only done once per key.
Every method call has to be safe
Your method doesn't itself mutate any fields, but, it invokes another method. That method has to be thread safe too; check docs or source. As @Ramiz mentioned, if that's Jackson's ObjectMapper, that is itself thread safe... except...
it also has to adhere to the rule.
Your state needs to be consistent
The reason I can definitely say your code as is cannot be termed 'no frills, no caveats thread safe' is the state of your object. Your User object is mutable, at least, its fields appear to be: They are not tagged final. Even if they were, the objects themselves may not be, but, at least, both Integer and String are immutable and thus trivially 'safe'.
Even with everything else thread safe, the object mapper could call user.getId();, then the thread gets pre-empted, some other code calls user.setId(1234); and then user.setName("Hello"), and then the mapper code continues and calls .getName(), which means the mapper now is writing out inconsistent data. That's not 'thread safe'.
Hence, thread safe is not that simple.
If you never actually mutate User during the call then it is probably thread safe, but note that something like this:
UserProcessor processor = new UserProcessor();
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
   // some processor that is handed user objects and writes them
   while (true) processor.process();
});

User u = new User();
u.setName("A");
u.setId(1);
processor.handle(u);

This isn't thread safe either. Without some sort of Happens-Before relationship, there is no guarantee that the processor thread can observe the changes that this thread (i.e. name "A" and ID 1) made.
Generally thread safety is extremely complicated; hence, if you see an opportunity to simplify, take it. If those fields can be final, make them so. Then this all goes away. For example, in the same snippet if it was User u = new User("A", 1); where the constructor is 'proper' (does not leak its reference) and the fields are final, that is threadsafe, due to some special rules about constructors and final fields. And you avoid the issue of inconsistency caused by other code mutating User in the middle of the mapper's operation.

In my case, the User object is mutable. But never gets modified after being passed to the static method. Are you saying that if multiple threads call this static method with different user objects, could cause it to not thread-safe eventhough the state is not changed for the user object after the object is built?

@skvcr Then it isn't thread safe unless there is some sort of Happens-Before relationship in between 'the last time User is mutated' and 'a reference to that object is provided to the mapper and it does its mapping thing'. Which there probably is, but that method does not guarantee it.

The static modifier does not guarantee thread-safety.
In your example, however, the method is thread-safe, because, as you already noted, the method does not read nor modify shared variables.
For your use case the following class will be thread-safe too if ObjectMapper is from the jackson library, as it is thread safe according to the docs:

Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls.

public class UtilityClass {
    static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String objToString(User user) {
         return mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    }

}

Later is recommended approach if the method is intended to be called frequently, because initialization of the ObjectMapper is cached.
